# How to identify root nodes in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

I have a python dictionary that is representing a graph. I wish to identify the root/independent nodes so that I can process them simultaneously and then the next nodes will become root/independent nodes. 
I am confused about how to implement this technique in python.

Below is a sample dictionary:

```
my_graph = {
            1:[4],
            2:[6],
            3:[9],
            4:[5,7],
            5:[8],
            6:[],
            7:[],
            8:[],
            9:[]
           }
```

I will divide the process into different frames. The expected result depending upon the above dictionary is given as:

1- start:
 root/independent nodes are = 1,2,3

2- after frame 1
 root/independent nodes are = 4,6,9

3- after frame 2
 root/independent nodes are = 5,7

4- after frame 3
 root/independent nodes are = 8

Edit 1:
 I am trying to get sequence in any form e.g. a list, array or any other similar data-structure to a dependency graph of nodes in given dictionary, where each child node is dependent on its parent node so cannot be processed before parent. As a next step, I wish to get some parallelism i.e. I can process all root nodes at once.

I have been reading about [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) and [luigui](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) but not sure if they are the ultimate solution or I can do it some simple way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please demonstrate it with code.

Comment: Could you give some more context? It would help answering your question if we saw what problem you would like to solve.

Comment: @thomi I have added an explanation under the tag 'Edit 1'.  If you still cannot understand me, kindly ask further questions I'd be happy to explain them. Or you can write what your current understanding of this problem is.

Comment: @sophros I am trying to figure out the solution on paper. I have written a lot of python scripts but that are just for testing different ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "topological sort". A simple algorithm is

1. build a mapping between nodes and number of "incoming" arcs
2. process nodes with 0 (those are "roots") and update the counters as you proceed (when you process a node decrement counter for all neighbors).

You may get to a stop before completion if the graph is not a tree (there are loops). In this case you will get to a point where the graph is not empty but there is no available root.

In your case

```
def tsort(graph): 
    counts = dict((k, 0) for k in graph) 
    for n, neighbors in graph.items(): 
        for nh in neighbors: 
            counts[nh] = counts[nh] + 1 
    while graph: 
        roots = [k for k in graph if counts[k] == 0] 
        if not roots: 
            raise RuntimeError("Cycles present, no topological sort possible") 
        print("roots", roots) 
        for r in roots: 
            print("Processing", r) 
            for nh in graph[r]: 
                counts[nh] -= 1 
            del graph[r]
```

Comment: @muruDiaz: yes... roots are all nodes without any "incoming" link and they can be more than one. The only problem are loops (in that case no topological sort is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to perform a [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

You can use the library, [toposort](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/) to do the heaving lifting for you, it will determine the dependencies and order in which the nodes should be processed:

```
import toposort

my_graph = {
            1:[4],
            2:[6],
            3:[9],
            4:[5,7],
            5:[8],
            6:[],
            7:[],
            8:[],
            9:[]
           }

# change values to sets (required by toposort)
for key, value in my_graph.items():
    my_graph[key] = set(value)

result = toposort.toposort(my_graph)
print(list(result))
```

> [{6, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 5}, {4}, {1}]

Comment: I don't think that's the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Much easier:

```
while d: #'d' is a dictionary
    roots = set(d).difference(*d.values())
    print(roots)
    [d.pop(k) for k in roots]
```

or in a recursive way:

```
def traverse(d):
    if d:
        roots = set(d).difference(*d.values())
        print(roots)
        [d.pop(k) for k in roots]
        return traverse(d)
```

Either way prints:

```
set([1, 2, 3])
set([4, 6, 9])
set([5, 7])
set([8])
```

Comment: Which one will be better for smaller and larger dictionaries? Could you share their performance comparison?